# React helpers to react components

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, local-storage

I have created a helpers function to reuse.
On my first component the helper functions is working well.
But when I use it on the other component. It's having a bug that when I add products to favorites it adds to the favorites but when I click on the other products it overwrite the previously added favorites.

my helpers

```js
function getFromLocalStorage(key) {
  return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key))
}

export function setToLocalStorage(key, data) {
  return localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(data))
}

export const favoriteProductsStorageKey = "favorites_products"

export function getAllFavoriteProducts() {
  return getFromLocalStorage(favoriteProductsStorageKey) || []
}

export function createFavoriteHelpers(favorites, setFavorites) {

  function addFavorite(product) {
    const isProductAlreadyFavorite = isProductInFavorites(product);

    if (isProductAlreadyFavorite) return;

    const newFavoriteProducts = [...favorites, product];

    setFavorites(newFavoriteProducts);
    setToLocalStorage(favoriteProductsStorageKey, newFavoriteProducts);
  }

  function removeFavorite(product) {
    const newFavoriteProducts = favorites.filter(
      (iteratedProduct) => iteratedProduct._id !== product._id
    );

    setFavorites(newFavoriteProducts);
    setToLocalStorage(favoriteProductsStorageKey, newFavoriteProducts);
  }

  function isProductInFavorites(product) {
    return favorites.some(
        (iteratedProduct) => iteratedProduct._id === product._id
    );
  }

  return {
    addFavorite,
      removeFavorite,
      isProductInFavorites,
  };
}
```

my 1st component that is working so well.

```js
const ProductList = ({ products }) => {
  const classes = useStyles()

  const [favorites, setFavorites] = useState(getAllFavoriteProducts())
  const favoriteHelpers = createFavoriteHelpers(favorites, setFavorites)

  return (
    <>
      <div className={classes.root}>
        {products?.map((product) => {
          return (
            <div className="ProductCard" key={product._id}>
              <div>
                <Link to="/shop" state={{ shop: product.shop }}>
                  <img
                    className="ProductImage"
                    src={product.imagePrimary}
                    alt={product.name}
                  />
                </Link>
                <div className="FavButton">
                  {favoriteHelpers.isProductInFavorites(product) ? (
                    <FavoriteIcon
                      fontSize="small"
                      style={{ fill: "red" }}
                      onClick={() => favoriteHelpers.removeFavorite(product)}
                    />
                  ) : (
                    <FavoriteIcon
                      fontSize="small"
                      style={{ fill: "gray" }}
                      onClick={() => favoriteHelpers.addFavorite(product)}
                    />
                  )}
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="ProductCardDetails">
                <div className="NameAndPrice">
                  <div className="ProductName">{product.name}</div>
                  <div className="ProductPrice">P{product.price}</div>
                </div>
                <div className="Description"> by {product.shop.name}</div>
              </div>
            </div>
          )
        })}
      </div>
    </>
  )
}

export default ProductList
```

the one that is having a bug on adding and removing.

```js
const ProductCard = ({ data }) => {

  const [favorites, setFavorites] = useState(getAllFavoriteProducts())
  const favoriteHelpers = createFavoriteHelpers(favorites, setFavorites)

  return (
    <div className="ProductCard">
      <div>
        <Link to="/product" state={{ product: data }}>
          <img
            className="ProductImage"
            src={data.imagePrimary}
            alt={data.name}
          />
        </Link>
        <div
          aria-hidden="true"
          className="AddButton"
          onClick={() => {
            addToBag(data)
            // useAddToBag(data)
          }}
          onKeyDown={() => {
            addToBag(data)
          }}
        >
          <AddIcon fontSize="small" />
        </div>
        <div className="FavButton">
          {favoriteHelpers.isProductInFavorites(product) ? (
            <FavoriteIcon
              fontSize="small"
              style={{ fill: "red" }}
              onClick={() => favoriteHelpers.removeFavorite(product)}
            />
          ) : (
            <FavoriteIcon
              fontSize="small"
              style={{ fill: "gray" }}
              onClick={() => favoriteHelpers.addFavorite(product)}
            />
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="ProductCardDetails">
        <div className="NameAndPrice">
          <div className="ProductName">{data.name}</div>
          <div className="ProductPrice">P{data.price}</div>
        </div>
        <div className="Description"> {data.description}</div>
      </div>
      <AddToBagDialog
        showDialog={dialogState.showDialog}
        message={dialogState.dialogMessage}
        onGotoBag={() => {
          setDialogState((prevState) => ({
            ...prevState,
            showDialog: false,
          }))
          navigate("/bagpage")
        }}
        onAddMoreProducts={() => {
          setDialogState((prevState) => ({
            ...prevState,
            showDialog: false,
          }))
        }}
      />
      <ConfirmationDialog
        showDialog={confirmDialogState.showDialog}
        message={confirmDialogState.dialogMessage}
        onConfirm={() => {
          updateBag([])
          updateBag((prevState) => [...prevState, product])
          setConfirmDialogState((prevState) => ({
            ...prevState,
            showDialog: false,
          }))
          setDialogState((prevState) => ({
            ...prevState,
            showDialog: true,
            dialogMessage: "Product added to bag",
            isError: false,
          }))
        }}
        onDecline={() => {
          setConfirmDialogState((prevState) => ({
            ...prevState,
            showDialog: false,
          }))
        }}
      />
    </div>
  )
}

export default ProductCard
```

While using Local storage the ProductList is working correctly when adding and removing to favorites, but on the ProductCard it is replacing the ones added before when adding a favorite.

Here [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/empty-river-jm94p?file=/src/components/Homemade/SearchPage/ProductList/index.js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each component initialize `[favorites, setFavorites]` with `getAllFavoriteProducts()` but from there they live separately.

So, when you update the favorites inside the first component, the state inside the second component doesn't get updated, and when you update from within the second component, it will overwrite the favorites inside `localStorage`.

If you need the two components to share the same state, you need to lift up the state on the [first common ancestor](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html#lifting-state-up).

Another solution could be to use the [Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) in order to share the state between the two components.

As asked by the question's author, here is a draft in order to show some example on how to solve the problem.

First you need to create (or edit) the common parent of the two components. Since I don't know your code I will post a basic component just to show you how to do the thing.

```
const Container = () => {
  const [favorites, setFavorites] = useState(getAllFavoriteProducts())

  return <div>
    <ProductList products={products} favorites={favorites} setFavorites={setFavorites} />
    <ProductCard data={data} favorites={favorites} setFavorites={setFavorites} />
  </div>
}
```

In this way the `favorites` are read from `localStorage` initially and the are keep inside the `Container` and passed down to `ProductList` and `ProductCard` together with the method `setFavorites` in order to edit the `favorites` state from inside each children component.

Then you need to edit each component in the following way:

```
const ProductList = ({ products, favorites, setFavorites }) => {
  // const [favorites, setFavorites] = useState(getAllFavoriteProducts()) ---> comment or delete this

  // ...rest of your code
}
const ProductCard = ({ data, favorites, setFavorites }) => {
  // const [favorites, setFavorites] = useState(getAllFavoriteProducts()) ---> comment or delete this

  // ...rest of your code
}
```

with these changes you should make it works, but since I don't have the code of your project I can't be sure. In any case I'm sure that with these tips you will be able to do everything you need.

Comment: hello can you show me some example? @Marco Nisi

Comment: @PinkyPromise I posted some example, please let me know if it helps you.

Comment: hello what if they dont have a parent component? @Marco Nisi

Comment: @PinkyPromise if the components are simblings then you could create a parent component for this purpose, that contains only the logic for `favorites` state management, just like in the example.

Comment: Hello I uploaded a sandbox for you to see the real output. in the local storage on the ProductList it is working well when adding and removing to favorites. but on the ProductCard it is replacing the ones added when adding a favorite. https://codesandbox.io/s/empty-river-jm94p?file=/src/components/Homemade/ShopPage/components/ProductCard.js @Marco Nisi

Comment: @PinkyPromise I tried a little and it seems to work for me. Can you explain to me every step that I need to take in order to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Hi if you will go to the search page. you can click the heart to add and click again to remove the favorites. but when you go to the home page then click 1 shop. then on the Menu you will see products also. there if you add 1 product to favorite, it adds, but when you add another one, it replaces the recently added favorite]

Answer (score 0):

To solve your problem partially, you need to provide the key of `localStorage` where your favorite products are saved when populating initial component's state using `getAllFavoriteProducts()`. Since, currently you are calling it without any key, so it will always return an empty array instead of retrieving the saved favorite products from `localStorage`.

So replace the line: `const [favorites, setFavorites] = useState(getAllFavoriteProducts())` with `const [favorites, setFavorites] = useState(getAllFavoriteProducts(favoriteProductsStorageKey))` in both the components.

However, if there is a chance for your components to be in mounted state simultaneously, then adding favorite products in one component won't affect the favorite products in other component's state as both of them have independent local state. To sync changes made from one component to the other component, you need to have some kind of shared state between them. To achieve this, you can either use a global state library like `redux` or `mobx` or keep favorites' state in a top level parent component and pass this state as props to both the components you've mentioned.